# Receiving json echo from PHP

Tags: php, android, json

I'm dealing with a problem here. I have my php code that sends me a User Array  with all the info inside. The problem is: how con i access to all this info from android? (not in a ugly way I'm gonna post here)

Any help will be appreciated.

My php File

```
<?php
$host = "mysql12.000webhost.com";
$user = "xxxx";
$password = "xxx";
$db = "xxxx";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);


    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $name, $age, $mail, $username, $password,$image);

    $user = array();

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $user[name] = $name;
        $user[age] = $age;
        $user[mail] = $mail;
        $user[username] = $username;
        $user[password] = $password;
        $user[image] = $image;
    }    
    echo json_encode($user);
    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

The way I'm dealing with the info:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { //Read till there is something available

                sb.append(line + "");//Reading and saving line by line - not all at once
            }

        line = sb.toString();

        String[] kvPairs = line.split(",");

        String[] nombreIn = kvPairs[0].split(":");
        String nombre_com = nombreIn[1].replaceAll(" \"", "");
        String nombre = nombre_com.replace("\"", "");
        ///TAQUIBIEEEEEEEN!!!


        String[] ageIn = kvPairs[1].split(":");
        int age = Integer.parseInt(ageIn[1]);

        String[] mailIn = kvPairs[2].split(":");
        String mail = mailIn[1].replaceAll("\"", "");

        String[] usernameIn = kvPairs[3].split(":");
        String username = usernameIn[1].replaceAll("\"", "");


        String[] passwordIn = kvPairs[4].split(":");
        String password = passwordIn[1].replaceAll("\"", "");

        String[] bitmstrIn = kvPairs[5].split(":");
        String[] bitmstrIn2 = bitmstrIn[1].split("\\}");
        String bitStr = bitmstrIn2[0].replaceAll("\n", "");;
        String biStrFin = bitStr.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
        String bitkok=biStrFin.substring(0, biStrFin.length() - 1);
```

For sure there has to be an easiest way to do it.

thanks!

Comment: Something preventing you from using something like `JSONObject jsonWe = new JSONObject(line);` ?

Comment: Gonna try it now, thanks! can you help me on how is the way to access info later?

Comment: Something like `jsonWe.getString("password");`. You should read the Android Dev manual because in some case you might want need to use JSONArray as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would retrieve information from your JSONString

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { //Read till there is something available
    sb.append(line + "");//Reading and saving line by line - not all at once
}

line = sb.toString();

JSONObject user = null;
try {
   user = new JSONObject(line);
} catch (JSONException e) {
   //code in case variable line isnt well format json string
}
if (user != null) {
   String name = user.getString('name');
   String age = user.getString('age');
   String mail = user.getString('mail');
   String userName = user.getString('username');
   String password = user.getString('password');
   String image = user.getString('image');
}
```